# How to debug CSP (including CSP cache)

Tags: firefox, content-security-policy

I am developing a page and for some reason I started getting this errors on our test server (replaced its hostname for security reasons):

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). injectGlobalHook.js:808:49
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://example.com/admin/assets/demo/default/base/scripts.bundle.js (“script-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://example.com/admin/runtime.4cbfbfa49b193f847ed1.js (“script-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://example.com/admin/polyfills.7e64f3b1273a474a8867.js (“script-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://example.com/admin/scripts.9ad8122b74233091de3d.js (“script-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://example.com/admin/main.53084d308f02a83449d8.js (“script-src”).
```

The problem is that this errors happen only to me, only on firefox and only when not using incognito.
I also don't have any CSP configuration in the project.

I assume the reason is that at some point there were some CSP rules on that server and they got cached.

How can I debug the reason why I am getting those errors and where can I find the cached CSP rules?

edit:
Forgot to mention, this errors are not specific to angular.
They appear on all scripts loaded from that domain including angular page, swagger api-doc and Symfony debugger.
I just used the angular one as example.

Comment: Do you have FF addons like NoSpript or PrivacyBadger?

Comment: I have quite a few addons, mostly development tools, but now that you mentioned those 2, maybe ublock is the reason.

Comment: Nevermind, I am dumb, I left "Disable JavaScript" turned on after testing something on the project and it affected the entire domain. Thanks for help.
You can write checking addons as answer and I will accept it.